# Ubuntu 11.10 can't detect my video card (nvidia gtx 560)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 11.10

I'm currently using Ubuntu 11.10 and it's a fresh install. I've already installed nvidia drivers through the terminal with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`, but Ubuntu still can't detect my current video card.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to reboot after installing the nvidia driver.

What happens when you run

```
gksu nvidia-settings
```

Should look someting like this

[image: nvidia settings]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lspci | grep nV
```

You should see something like this:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 1244 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: nVidia Corporation Device 0bee (rev a1)
```

Anyway, in your image I can see it says "standard experience" so your 3d acceleration is working. Try to open jockey:

```
gksu jockey-gtk
```

It will tell you if your drivers are properly installed.